# Similar sounds to Tcha-Badjo's gypsy jazz?

Tags: similar-artists

For years now I've been listening to whatever tracks by [Tcha-Badjo](http://www.tchabadjo.com/) that I could scrape up. They haven't released their albums online in any way yet, but they have a few live versions of album and non-album songs on YouTube.

To me, their style of gypsy jazz is very unique. They aren't like most gypsy jazz artists such as Django Reinhardt because they travel Europe and record new songs with local musicians which results in varying sounds that are all still alike somehow.

Does anyone know how to find artists similar to Tcha-Badjo? I've searched everywhere (for both "gypsy jazz" and "jazz manouche"). I'm not looking for big bands or solo artists but small groups of tightly knit performers.

Comment: Tags are added created when they are needed.  It generally takes a few questions with the same subject matter to get a tag created.  I don't think these tags are needed at the moment.

Comment: @Jacob New tags are created when they're used by just one question. Tags are needed when there is a question regarding them. These tags are absolutely needed.

Answer (score 2):

For the French scene, you can search for "Jazz Manouche". For instance Biréli Lagrène, which I heard live once, is quite famous. Unfortunately, I don't know small groups to suggest...

Comment: I've also searched jazz manouche many times. I couldn't find anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

Go straight to the source, and follow the trails from there.

Gypsy Jazz was pioneered by Django Reinhardt at the Hot Club of France in Paris in the 20s.

[Minor Swing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcE1avXFJb4) is probably the most identifiable song of the genre.

Comment: Searching for Django Reinhardt doesn't get me anywhere near the style of Tcha-Badjo. I've tried many times.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking up Hot Club + any major city and you're likely to find a gypsy jazz group. A lot of groups use that as part of their name. Also things like Hot Club Sandwich or 12th Avenue Hot Club. Also the top gypsy jazz solo artists do a lot of great and interesting things. Bireli Lagrene, the Rosenbergs, the Schmidts, Django's relatives, Jon Jorgensen, Robin Nolan, and lots of others I know I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 1):

At best guess you're looking for a contemporary take on a classic sub-genre.  You don't want the classics, you want an updated sound. I'd suggest a search for "*modern* gypsy jazz."  Here are some links I found that provided suggestions that sound --to my ear at least --similar to the referenced band:

http://www.djangobooks.com/forum/discussion/12900/modern-pop-rock-songs-in-a-gypsy-jazz-style

http://www.npr.org/sections/ablogsupreme/2012/10/05/162332936/djangos-legacy-21st-century-gypsy-jazz

Comment: The link to djangobooks.com seems to be broken, could you take a look?